Install GMP library on Mac OS and PyCharm
I'm trying to run my Cython project. And one of the header is gmpxx.h.
Even though I already installed the gmp library using brew install gmp. I could not run my cython file with  python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace.
fatal error: 'gmpxx.h' file not found

#include <gmpxx.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1

So I use brew list gmp to check the location of the  gmpxx.h header.
So it is actually inside /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include/ folder.
With Xcode, I can just add the location into the header search paths.
But I'm trying to do the same thing with Pycharm.
How do I add the location of my gmpxx.h header to pycharm?
I need a little help. Please kindly give me your take. Thank you.

So I added the library location directly into setup.py file.
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extension = Extension(
    "Class Name",
    sources=["Something"
    ],
    include_dirs=[
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include",  # Include directory for GMP headers
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/include/gmp",  # Additional include directory for GMP headers
    ],
    libraries=["gmpxx", "gmp"],
    library_dirs=[
        "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.3.0/lib",  # Directory containing libgmpxx.dylib
    ],
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++17", "-O3"],
    language="c++"
)

setup(
    name="Class Name",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    package_data={"Class Name": ["*.pyi"]},
    ext_modules=cythonize(extension,
                          compiler_directives={"language_level":3},
                          annotate=True),
    zip_safe=False
)


The documentation of build_ext states that the build_ext subcommand honors the standard environment variables.
So setting the following environment variables before invoking setup.py should do the trick:
export CPPFLAGS=$(pkg-config gmp --cflags)
export LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config gmp --libs)

You can also execute the pkg-config commands on your terminal and copy the values to the appropriate environment variables in PyCharm yourself.
For development you might want to hardcode these paths in the include_dirs and library_dirs attributes of the setup.py file.

I tried to run the 2 export lines above but it didn't work out. I still get the same error on my Cython project

Please edit your question to a [mre], then.
